# What does the option "convert to web application" do if I select it in visual studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

What does the option “convert to web application” do if I select it in visual studio? If I do convert my site to a web application what are the advantages? Can I go back?

Comment: The differences between Web App projects and web sites have been [answered already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798/aspnet-web-site-or-web-project). Hope that helps.

Comment: You might want to change your question title since it doesn't really match your question. What it does and what are the advantages are 2 different things.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, it converts your web site to a web application project. As for the advantages, here is some further reading:

MSDN comparison -- [Comparing Web Site Projects and Web Application Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730880(VS.80).aspx#wapp_topic5)

Webcast on ASP.NET -- [Web Application Projects vs. Web Site Projects in Visual Studio 2008](http://www.asp.net/LEARN/webcasts/webcast-236.aspx)

*"In this webcast, by request, we examine the differences between web application projects and web site projects in Microsoft Visual Studio 2008. We focus specifically on the reasons you would choose one over the other and explain how to make informed decisions when creating a Web solution*"

The primary difference (to me) between a web application project and a web site is how things gets compiled.  In web sites each page has its code-behind compiled into a separate library, whereas in web applications all code-behind gets compiled into a single library.

There are advantages and disadvantages to both, it really depends. It's also often a matter of [opinion](http://blog.madskristensen.dk/post/Web-Application-Projects-vs-Web-Site-Projects.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

[Also Answered Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43019/what-does-vs-2008s-convert-to-website-mean) so go vote that answer up, not this one. **Don't give me credit**

> There are two types of web applications in ASP.NET: The Web Site and Web Application Project. The difference between the two are discussed here:
>
> [Difference between web site and web applications in Visual Studio 2005](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/1520-Difference-between-web-site-web-application.aspx)
>
> Convert to Website allows you to convert a Web Application Project to a Web Site.
>
> Visual Studio 2003 used the Web Application Project style, but initially VS2005 only supported web sites. VS2005 SP1 brought back Web Applications.
>
> If you don't want to convert your project to a web site, apply SP1 if you're using VS2005. VS2008 can support either.

Answer (score 1):

Visual studio 2010 will show this option Even if your project is started as a Project(Not website). This may be an Error from VS 2010.

Comment: The "Convert to Web Application" is for converting pages and classes to use partial classes in a Web Application project after you have included those pages and classes from a Web Site project.