# package a visual studio project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have an asp.net app in visual studio and it's starting to contain quite a few files. I remenber seeing a .sln file format that converts the entire files into one file. How does this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution (.SLN) files don't allow you to "package" your project. A solution file is just a list of your sub-projects.

Given that you've tagged this "asp.net", I'm guessing that you've got a "Web Site" project. You might find it easier to manage if you convert it to a "Web Application" project. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85513/what-does-the-option-convert-to-web-application-do-if-i-select-it-in-visual-stu) for more discussion.

In fact, if you've got a "Web Site" project, you've already got a .SLN file. It'll be somewhere under `C:\Users\frenchie\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects`.

Whatever you do, you're going to end up with a bunch of folders containing a bunch of files. Read up on the differences between Website Projects and Web Application Projects before doing the conversion.

Comment: for now, I just have all my files, including the database, in subfolders of a folder located in the root directory of my laptop. I didn't see an sln file. What's the conversion about?