# How to "publish directory from a web server"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, msdn, sample

I am interested in running this [MSDN ASP.NET sample](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=22117) (more info on its content on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479306.aspx)).
The install instructions mentions:

> To setup this example on your PC (...) publish the 'Quantize' directory from your web server. It should be published as http://[localhost]/quantize.

When I tried to open the solution, it failed to load the Quantize.csproj project.
I have no experience in ASP.NET, but C# desktop application are ok.
What does "publish a directory" mean, and how can I quickly get the code running to test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that you need to create virtual directory "quantize" at IIS and link it to folder with this project.
To open the project separatly in VS just open Quantize.csproj.webinfo with any text-editor and remove line `<Web URLPath....`

Comment: How do I create a virtual directory? I just found [this MSDN page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172138), do you know a more straightforward tutorial? I just tried to remove the URLPath line in csproj.webinfo, and to replace the path by "", but VS says that web server could not be found. Did I misread your answer?

Comment: You need to remove not the path but hole line (with xml tag).

To add Virtual directory open Internet Information Services Manager, go to Sites, right-click Default Web Site and select Add Virtual Directory.

Comment: Thanks! I used [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763170.aspx) to open IIS manager (it was not there by default so I had to add it via `Control Panel > Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on or off > Internet Information Services`. Now Visual Studio told me to [convert my project to a web application](http://stackoverflow.com/q/85513/758666) and [register ASP.net 4.0 on the web server](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5836228/758666). I'll try to fix that next.