# Project Types in ASP.NET

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, web-applications, project-types

How do I create a Web Application Project in VS 2008? How is it different from a "WebSite" project?

Comment: There is a similar question here thats already answered:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43019/what-does-vs-2008s-convert-to-website-mean Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

File--New--Project

instead of File--New--Web Site

It acts as a different container all together and the compile model is different.

ScottGu provided some details when they were first launched: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/05/08/445742.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that Web application uses .csproj file which holds the information about all the files in the project. What difference does it make? Using web site model you can add new files **without** visual studio, since adding new files doesn't require csproj file modifications, but using Web application model you can not.
I personally prefer Web application type.

Answer (score 0):

People have adequately identified many differences, but let me add this broader stroke:

Web Application Projects are architecturally consistant with the other project types in .Net, whereas WebSites deviate and really seem like a throwback to the VS 2003 days.

For this reason, my opinion is that WAP's are more elegant (especially when you have more than one project in a solution).

Comment: VS2003 had a web application, whereas they broked it in VS2005 before bringing it back in SP1.  It's really a throwback to the "classic" days...  *shudder*

Comment: You're right actually... It does feel more like Classic. *sympathy shudder*